# Google Map Version in SAS Planet

Tags: google-earth

I would like to find out how to access google satellite map version to update on SAS planet.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqpu792C1ic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Google Maps in your browser.  Open the element inspector (F12 in Chrome, Firefox and Edge).  Search for `khms0.google.com/kh/v` in the html (ctrl + F). Note the number in the html after the search string (at the time of writing it is `u003d845`).  The number you want is after the 'u003d' part (i.e. 845 in this case).

Or you can just go to the [nightly builds page](https://www.gisenglish.com/2018/06/download-sas-planet-nightly-all.html) and have a look there.  It is listed clearly!

Comment: I have been trying for a year if not years first solution suggested, but it works on one computer and not the rest. Not too sure why. The last solution is easy, thank you so much.